# Mule - Connect timeout

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have a problem with setting Connection Timeout on HTTP Request Connector (not to confuse with Response Timeout) with Mule 3.7. 
Configuration I'm using is not changing this arbitrary ~5 second delay between initiating connection and throwing "java.net.ConnectException: Connect timeout", even if https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/tcp-transport-reference suggests that setting connectionTimeout attribute should do the trick.

What am I missing? Is there any other way to specify this timeout? Or is this dependent on the OS?

Flow ilustrating the problem:

```
<mule xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:tcp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp" xmlns:tls="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:quartz="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz/current/mule-quartz.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls/current/mule-tls.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp/current/mule-tcp.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd">
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration"  host="123.123.123.123" port="4444"  doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" responseTimeout="30000" usePersistentConnections="false" >
        <tcp:client-socket-properties connectionTimeout="30000" timeout="30000"/>
    </http:request-config>
    <flow name="connectionTimeoutTestFlow">
        <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="Knock" repeatInterval="60000" responseTimeout="100000" doc:name="Quartz">
            <quartz:event-generator-job/>
        </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
        <logger message="Start Request" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/debug/index.jsp" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Output:

```
INFO  2016-02-10 12:53:55,736 [[connectionTimeoutTest].connectionTimeoutTestFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Start Request
ERROR 2016-02-10 12:54:01,321 [[connectionTimeoutTest].connectionTimeoutTestFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: NullPayload
Type                  : org.mule.api.MessagingException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
Payload               : {NullPayload}
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html
********************************************************************************
Exception stack is:
1. Connect timeout (java.net.ConnectException)
  org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.SingleEndpointPool$ConnectCompletionHandler:1283 (null)
2. java.net.ConnectException: Connect timeout (java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException)
  org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl$Sync:349 (null)
3. java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connect timeout (java.io.IOException)
  org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.GrizzlyHttpClient:234 (null)
4. Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: NullPayload (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester:287 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
java.net.ConnectException: Connect timeout
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.SingleEndpointPool$ConnectCompletionHandler.cancelled(SingleEndpointPool.java:1283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl.notifyCompletionHandlers(SafeFutureImpl.java:185)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl.done(SafeFutureImpl.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl$Sync.innerCancel(SafeFutureImpl.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl.cancel(SafeFutureImpl.java:247)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.SingleEndpointPool$ConnectTimeoutWorker.doWork(SingleEndpointPool.java:1351)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.SingleEndpointPool$ConnectTimeoutWorker.doWork(SingleEndpointPool.java:1343)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.DelayedExecutor$DelayedRunnable.run(DelayedExecutor.java:158)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

********************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a global configuration, defined at the top of your .xml, in which you specify Timeout for all your services, in example:

```
<configuration defaultTransactionTimeout="300000" defaultResponseTimeout="300000" doc:name="Configuration">
    <default-threading-profile poolExhaustedAction="RUN"/>
</configuration>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the http timeout in the http global config, you can do something like below:

```
<https:connector
    name="HTTP_HTTPS"
    cookieSpec="netscape"
    validateConnections="false"
    sendBufferSize="0"
    receiveBufferSize="0"
    receiveBacklog="0"
    clientSoTimeout="1000"
    serverSoTimeout="1000"
    socketSoLinger="1000"
    doc:name="HTTP-HTTPS"
    socketMaxWait="1000"
    connectionTimeout="1000"
    keepAlive="true">
```